# virtualenv is activated but pip freeze return all system packages

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, python, pip, virtualenv

I installed virtualenv using:

```
python -m pip install virtualenv
```

When I create a new env using this command:

```
virtualenv env
```

Then activate it:

```
source env/bin/activate
```

When I type pip freeze, it returns all the python packages I have installed, however, I didn't install anything yet on the env.

Note: I tried to install virtualenv with pip and apt-get, and I got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu packages `virtualenv` in a different way. While in other environments when you create a new virtualenv, it is empty, Ubuntu packs a lot of packages inside a newly created virtualenv.

Anthony Sottile made some interesting videos on this topic and also explains how to get virtualenv not from Ubuntu package manager, but from scratch - and turns out, this one is able to create new virtualenvs with zero packages inside.

```
curl --location --output virtualenv.pyz https://bootstrap.pypa.io/virtualenv.pyz
```

You can then do a `python3 virtualenv.pyz venv` - and into this venv you can install virtualenv. And then put it on your path. Sounds complicated? It is well worth it.

This uptodate virtualenv is up to 10 times faster than the one from Ubuntu packages and it has zero packages inside a new virtualenv.

I recommend to watch this video...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXmYKh0eTQ8&ab_channel=anthonywritescode